# How to change font-size of selected text in notepad++?

Tags: interface, notepad++

I can able to change the whole document font-size. Is there anyway to change font-size for particular texts like changing colors for selected text?

Comment: Is that a programming question?

Comment: No. neither [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179057/notepad-manually-highlight-selected-text-like-microsoft-word-does)

Comment: Did you find your answer? And @helb , it's always nice to help.

Comment: No @hzq . I have tried but didn't spend much time on this

Answer (score 0):

Only for colors you can use EnhanceAnyLexer plugin, and made some regex for match with your texts.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).