# How can I highlight selected lines permanently?

Tags: pycharm, highlighting

I don’t only want to select the lines … I need to change the actual background of the selected text (for example to yellow) and have it stay yellow when I am done selecting it. Such as the following question explains [Notepad++ manually highlight selected text like Microsoft word does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179057/notepad-manually-highlight-selected-text-like-microsoft-word-does) except for the fact that I need to accomplish this in Pycharm as opposed to Notepad++

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: It's doesn't have the same visual effect, but why not just set a bookmark?